# Iterate over pages | selenium | ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, twitter, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

Please find the attached screenshot.
page consist of 20 tweets in the 1 tweet table. and 20 tweets per page respectively in each tweet table 2,3,4,5. I am able to fetch 1 tweets table i.e first 20 tweets. but how do fetch all 5 tweets-table? as **2** is not **button** as highlighted in screenshot.

I tried with full xpath however it is giving

```
second_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
 '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]').click()
```

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

code for first page i.e 20 tweets:

```
driver.get("https://www.trackmyhashtag.com/")

form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='container']")
usrinput = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input')
usrinput.clear()
usrinput.send_keys("india")

loginbt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/button')
loginbt.click()
time.sleep(5)

ad = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button')
ad.click()
time.sleep(5)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/aside/nav/div/ul/li[2]/a')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
actions.click().perform()
time.sleep(5)

ad=wait.until(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button'))


actions = ActionChains(driver)

rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@role='row' and(@class)]")
for i in range(1,len(rows)+1):
    row = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//tr[@role='row' and(@class)])[" + str(i) + "]")
    actions.move_to_element(row).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
    row = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//tr[@role='row' and(@class)])[" + str(i) + "]")
    name = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='tweet-name']").text
    content = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]").text
    date = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]").text
    impressions = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[6]").text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have scraped all 20 tweets from page 1, you need to scroll down till end and then click on page 2, and repeat the same process for all pages.

**Full code :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_settings.cookies": 2})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = options)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.trackmyhashtag.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

actions = ActionChains(driver)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "search_keyword"))).send_keys("India", Keys.RETURN)

def close_up():
    time.sleep(1)
    actions.move_to_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-dismiss='modal']"))))
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-dismiss='modal']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
    time.sleep(1)

def check_model_winodows():
    try:
        if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(//button[@data-dismiss='modal'])[1]")) >0:
            print("Pop up is visible")
            close_up()
        else:
            print("Pop up is not visible")
    except:
        print("Something went wrong")
        pass

check_model_winodows()
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick*='preview-tweets']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
#wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ""))).click()
check_model_winodows()
total_number_of_tweet_row = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tbody/tr"))
print(total_number_of_tweet_row)

page_number = 2
total_number_of_pages = 5
for a in range(total_number_of_pages):
    j = 0
    for i in range(total_number_of_tweet_row):
        check_model_winodows()
        elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tbody/tr")
        time.sleep(1)
        final_ele = elems[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]")
        print("code worked till here")
        print(final_ele.text)
        j = j + 1
        check_model_winodows()
    driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//a[text()='{page_number}']"))).click()
    page_number = page_number + 1
    if page_number == 5:
       break
```

**Output :**

```
"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" C:/Users/panabh02/PycharmProjects/SeleniumSO/Chrome.py
Pop up is visible
Pop up is visible
20
Pop up is visible
code worked till here
RT @TarekFatah: Here comes the threat to India by the Pakistani Taliban. “We will fly the Pakistan flag over Delhi in less than 24 hours,...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
@cz_binance @Btcexpertindia @binance @cz_binance you are popular in South India also 
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @narendramodi: The new Drone Rules usher in a landmark moment for this sector in India. The rules are based on the premise of trust and?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @priya_malviy24: #रेल_ग्रुपD_परीक्षा_कराओ It is our new India/digital India where election campaign...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @sardesairajdeep: Part of the golden 50s generation when English cricketers came through the Oxbridge system. No one I am told straight?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @SuryawaSingh: @NaveenK81494169 ना तख्त चाहिए , ना ताज चाहिए , हमें तो बस ops ?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @harshasherni: Mesmerizing view Somewhere near Vattavada a village in Idukki district in the state of Kerala, India.  @KeralaTourism ht...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @vivekagnihotri: 100% lobbying for vegan brands, almond milk etc. They just want @Amul_Coop to shut down. India is the largest milk prod?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @arslansaduzai: 64/n A woman is attacked, passing by men watch motionlessly. The incident took place on #InternationalWomensDay in Delhi?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @Chhotalikharii: India's farmer protest 273 days, 601 deaths #9MonthsOfFarmersProtes
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
@BSNL_HR @airtelindia @MCManesar @DoT_India Village Baskushla doesn't have any broadband service, ppl struggling to do WFH, students struggl...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @DennisCricket_: India have announced that Abhinandan will bat at 3 in the next Test. "Not even he crashes as bad as what we just saw?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
#JammuAndKashmir | Attack on press freedom': J&amp;K HC quashes FIR against journalist for reporting police torture. @naseerganai @JmuKmrPo...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
@FOBDoda @sikander_Quresh The freedom struggle is incomplete without talking about the famous Quit India Movement &amp; its phases. In th...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @ErikSolheim: Incredible India !  Reverse waterfall in Naneghat, Maharashtra .
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @Sharanyashettyy: Very instructive. Chinese nationals are now giving up their citizenship to hide their allegiance. As a country we need?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @narendramodi: The new Drone Rules usher in a landmark moment for this sector in India. The rules are based on the premise of trust and?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @CPhhp: #Run4India #AzadiKaMahotsav 103 cdts of 1 Pb Bn NCC of Amritsar Gp participated in the Fit India Freedom Run org by Distt Admi?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @sanjeevaiacewa: #SamePayForSameWork #PayRevisionFrom2017 Sir we NACP EMPLOYEES working in very low pay are requesting you to please RE?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @NamdevVaishu: HAPPY BIRTHDAY RUBINA has started Trending last Night and still has its place in india Trend list Another proof of organi?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @narendramodi: The new Drone Rules usher in a landmark moment for this sector in India. The rules are based on the premise of trust and?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
Ghosts make for a busy night aboard the Star of India paranormal #Radio
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @IMinakshiJoshi: #India में #Corona के मामले बढ़े. पिछले 24 घंटे में 46 हजार ...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @theskindoctor13: @ANI TaIiban didn't kiII him, hate did. Same hate that in India RSS harbours for minorities. Hence proved RSS is respo?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @idnani_nandini: Sad moment 140 Sikh Brothers denied Pilgrimage in India All held up by Taliban didn't allowed them to reach #Kabulair?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @ndtvindia: पुलिस अफसरों के सत्ताधारी दलों के साथ गठजोड़ पर...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @BiotechClinical: @MSWA123 @AmitV_Deshmukh @of_interns @vikalp_ek @AyurvedaStuden1 @Ayurtalk45 @AiAyushMedUnity @UnionAyush @BpmtSc @war?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @FXMC1957: 26 August 1910. Mother Teresa (Agnesë Bojaxhiu) was born in what is now Skopje, North Macedonia. She engaged in charitable ef...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @MinNara1227: #8MBrightsHug Trending 1 Worldwide  1 Thailand  1 Malaysia  1 Indonesia  1 Taiwan ...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
1989 batch IPS and Dg vigilance PV ramashastri appointed as New ADG @BSF_India. @ips_up @Uppolice @gyanu999 @Live_Gyan
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @itzzOriana: • Sachin vaze who's suspended for 17Years, but was granted bail &amp; later reinstated in June2020. • On 6th June, MGov...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @narendramodi: The new Drone Rules will tremendously help start-ups and our youth working in this sector. It will open up new possibilit?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @latestly: Man Dodges Security Officials at Mumbai Airport, Flies to Bareilly on Friend's Ticket; Arrested #Mumbai #Bareilly #MumbaiAirp?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @Atheist_Krishna: At present who is the worst Chief Minister in India?
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
@realSonuNigam0 Agree @RahulGandhi @SoniaGhandhiIND Declare India a Hindu Rashtra
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @ErikSolheim: Solar roof top is taking off in India ! Gujarat is leading the charge in installed capacity. @zubinashara https://...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @RedmiIndia: Prepare for finer things in life cause, it will be our FIRST TIME EVER in India with Qualcomm® Chipset! Ready for the "...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @PramodK88791564: @YouTubeIndia Gyan Gaming youtube channel got hacked ! What happens this youtube india @_GyanSujan_ @gamer_2b
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @IndiaTales7: One of the highest waterfalls in India- Witness the Majesty of Nature. #DekhoApnaDesh #IncredibleIndia  https://t...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @RonaldLampard8: Indonesia berada di bawah China, India, Amerika Serikat, Brasil, dan Jepang. Per Rabu (25/8) sebanyak 59 juta orang tel?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @yasasreevinnu: The question that haunt me every time Why Salman not concentrated on south India #Salmanakhan #33YearsOfSalmanKhanEra
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @narendramodi: My valued colleague, Shri @alphonstourism has made a commendable effort to encapsulate facets of India’s reform journey ...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @sparrow_grl_: कोरोना की लग चुकी है वैक्सीन, फिर क्यों कॉलेज ख?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @KrantiKKumar: खुशखबरी !!! All India Quota Medical Seats में 10% EWS आरक्षण लागू नही हो...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @Me_For_Photon: Only Disha Salian case will open the lock of Sushant's case. Both the murders are connected. - SSR DISHA MURDER LINKE?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
@mifz4L Ni north india do mmg keling kasta biol
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @Pradeep19951213: @AshwiniVaishnaw @UmangOfficial_ @_DigitalIndia @GoI_MeitY @PMOIndia @PIB_India #रेल_ग्रुपD_परी?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @ZpopF: Hlo GalaxZ, So I have been posting z stars quiz on my Instagram Stories you can join if you like to Link ?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @h59851687: From 'मैं देश नहीं बिकने दूंगा' to 'मैं सब कुछ बेच दूंग...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @Omkar_Raii: .@GoI_MeitY planning to support 300 tech startups by providing seed funding, mentorship &amp; market access and create 100 u...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @TrendsOfSTR: Our king #SilambarasanTR Tag on Trending in India level  Time to Lead .. #Maanaadu #VendhuThanindhath...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @MeghUpdates: India can be a $1 trillion market by 2025: Walmart
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @arslansaduzai: 37/n A woman resident of Ranwas village #India under Para police post in #Jhabua, #MadhyaPradesh, was forced to carry he?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @VinayKu86268222: @SarjuRamSahu1 @Jayendr10987039 @NaveenK81494169 @DRMSSY #NPSनिजीकरणभारतछोड़ो #NPSन?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @sanjeevaiacewa: #SamePayForSameWork #PayRevisionFrom2017 Sir we NACP EMPLOYEES working in very low pay are requesting you to please RE?...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @jorloplaz: Y las variantes: A) “La variante india hace estragos y hay que vacunar a todos”. Pero: B) En La India esa variante ha d...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
code worked till here
RT @nitinagarwalINC: From 'मैं देश नहीं बिकने दूंगा' to 'मैं सब कुछ बेच दू...
Pop up is visible
Something went wrong
Pop up is visible
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the data from first page tweets. Then check if there is a next page button enabled. If so - scroll the page up and then click the next page button and fetch the new data and check the next page button again. If enabled - click it, otherwise - stop the loop.

```py
driver.get("https://www.trackmyhashtag.com/")

form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='container']")
usrinput = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input')
usrinput.clear()
usrinput.send_keys("india")

loginbt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/button')
loginbt.click()
time.sleep(5)

ad = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button')
ad.click()
time.sleep(5)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/aside/nav/div/ul/li[2]/a')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
actions.click().perform()
time.sleep(5)

ad=wait.until(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button'))


actions = ActionChains(driver)
next_page_link_css = 'li.paginate_button.page-item.next a'
next_page_css = 'li.paginate_button.page-item.next'

while True:
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@role='row' and(@class)]")
    for i in range(1,len(rows)+1):
        time.sleep(1)
        row = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//tr[@role='row' and(@class)])[" + str(i) + "]")
        actions.move_to_element(row).perform()
        time.sleep(1)
        row = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//tr[@role='row' and(@class)])[" + str(i) + "]")
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='tweet-name']").text
        content = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]").text
        date = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]").text
        impressions = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[6]").text
    next_page_class = driver.find_element_by_css(next_page_css).get_attribute("class")
    if not 'disabled' in next_page_class:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        next_page_link_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(next_page_link_css)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page_link_btn)
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I am having rough time, running OP code, it does not work, it didn't work yesterday as well. yesterday it was stale element, now it is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\panabh02\PycharmProjects\SeleniumSO\Chrome.py", line 54, in <module>
    ad=wait.until(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button'))
  File "C:\Users\panabh02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable

Comment: Let's wait for OP response.

Comment: if not disabled in next_page_class:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not module @Prophet and i ahve used find_element_by_css_selector instead of find_element_by_css as it was giving error.

Comment: Sure, sorry. `disabled` is a string here

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="#" aria-controls="tweets_table" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0" class="page-link">...</a> is not clickable at point (844, 646). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal fade action-modal show" id="previewModalPOP" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="previewModal" aria-modal="true" style="padding-right: 15px; display: block;">...</div>

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css(next_page_link_css).click() this one . i have used driver.find_element_by_css_selector(next_page_link_css).click() instead

Comment: Ah, sure, sorry. My typo...
Try if it works correct now. I changed regular click with JS executor click

Comment: sorry i didn't get it, what should i change ? in click ??

Comment: See my code in the answer. I have updated it

Comment: First iteration  gets completed successfully for second it is giving error- line >actions.move_to_element(row).perform()                                                           error > selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: Well, strange. I added one more delay before getting the row element and increased the delay after going to the next page. Hope this will help