# document.scrollingElement is not working . Not able to scroll down for inspecting elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

Please find the aatched screenshot.

and Below code is printing only first 4-5 rows which is visible in the screenshot.
It is not scrolling down and inspecting element it is prining blank spaces.

Same code is running succesfully without i write code written in main function outside the function.

[image]

```
  def close_up(driver, actions):
        time.sleep(1)
        actions.move_to_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-dismiss='modal']"))))
        button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-dismiss='modal']")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
        time.sleep(1)
    
    
    def check_model_winodows(driver, actions):
        try:
            if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(//button[@data-dismiss='modal'])[1]")) > 0:
                # print("Pop up is visible")
                close_up(driver, actions)
            else:
                print("")
        except:
            # print("Something went wrong")
            pass
        return driver, actions
    
    
    def main(hashtag):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})
        options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_settings.cookies": 2})
    
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/tukaram/chromedriver', options=options)
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(50)
        driver.get("https://www.trackmyhashtag.com/")
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "search_keyword"))).send_keys(hashtag, Keys.RETURN)
    
        check_model_winodows(driver, actions)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        time.sleep(3)
        button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick*='preview-tweets']")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
        # wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick*='preview-tweets']"))).click()
        check_model_winodows(driver, actions)
        total_number_of_tweet_row = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tbody/tr"))
        # print(total_number_of_tweet_row)
        rank = 1
        page_number = 2
        total_number_of_pages = 5
        myhashtag = {}
        for a, idx in enumerate(range(total_number_of_pages)):
            print("idx>>>>", idx)
            j = 0
            for i in range(total_number_of_tweet_row):
                check_model_winodows(driver, actions)
                elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tbody/tr")
                time.sleep(1)
                # final_ele = elems[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]")
                # print("code worked till here")
                name = elems[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='tweet-name']").text
                print("name>", name)
                myhashtag['user_name'] = name
    
                userid = elems[j].find_element_by_tag_name("td").text
                userid = userid.partition('@')[2]
                userid = '@' + userid
                print("userid>", userid)
                myhashtag['user_screen_name'] = userid
    
                content = elems[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]").text
                print("content", content)
                myhashtag['content'] = content
    
                date = elems[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//td[3]").text
                print("1>>>>", date)
                date = str(date).replace("\n", " ")
                print("2>>>", date)
                date = datetime.strptime(date, '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p')
                print("3>>>", date)
                date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
                print("date", date)
                myhashtag['articleDate'] = date
    
                engm = elems[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//td[4]").text
                print("engagement", engm)
                myhashtag['engagement'] = engm
    
                impressions = elems[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//td[6]").text
                print("impressions", impressions)
                myhashtag['impressions'] = impressions
    
                myhashtag['rank'] = rank
                rank = rank + 1
                j = j + 1
    
                print(myhashtag)
    
                check_model_winodows(driver, actions)
            driver.execute_script(
                "var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = "
                "scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//a[text()='{page_number}']"))).click()
            page_number = page_number + 1
            print("Page numberrrr", page_number)
            if page_number == 7:
                break
        driver.quit()
        return driver, actions
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        for x in add_data.words:
            main(x)
```

add_data.py ->

```
words = ['India','@pakistan'] #words to crawl
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Same code is running succesfully without i write code written in main function outside the function.` ?

Comment: Actually our last solution was working perfectly -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68933612/iterate-over-pages-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-message-elemen/68933991#68933991  but after i made few changes added some functions. so it was printing only first few lines , not able to scroll down and print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need to scroll to each row to extract details. I added `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",elems[j])` in the code, and it extracted all the details. Try this once.

```
    for a, idx in enumerate(range(total_number_of_pages)):
        print("idx>>>>", idx)
        j = 0
        for i in range(total_number_of_tweet_row):
            check_model_winodows(driver, actions)
            elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tbody/tr")
            time.sleep(1)
            # final_ele = elems[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]")
            # print("code worked till here")
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",elems[j]) # Line to be addded.
            name = elems[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='tweet-name']").text
```

Comment: able to go till end of the page by adding that line, however,after that            `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//a[text()='{page_number}']"))).click()` is not working. beacuse of that line i guess as it is scrolling down !

Comment: @pkk - Had already tried it. Tried again, it works fine. Extracts data and clicks on the next page number. Share what the complete error message you are getting.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="#" aria-controls="tweets_table" data-dt-idx="..." tabindex="0" class="page-link">2</a> is not clickable at point (1647, 726). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal fade action-modal show" id="previewModalPOP" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="previewModal" aria-modal="true" style="padding-right: 15px; display: block;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)

Comment: @pkk - At last I get a error for `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//a[text()='{page_number}']"))).click()` because, it searching to click on page number `6` but the there are only 5 pages for Hashtag `India`.

Comment: No ! page number is set to 2 first so after 1st page it should go for 2nd page. after that page number is getting incremented. But it is giving error on first page only. Are you able to go till 5th page ??

Comment: @pkk - yes, was able to go to till 5th page

Comment: @pkk - You need first check for page `7` and if the `Next` option is enabled so that if there is no 6th page it will break. If not it will wait to click on the next page. I Have updated the same in the answer.

Comment: okay i will add that logic but i am not able to move to 2 page. `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//a[text()='{page_number}']"))).click()`  i tried 10-15 times. still no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236880/discussion-between-pkk-and-pmadhu).

Comment: @pkk - Link for complete code - [Link](https://pastebin.com/dvDP24z6)